# Why does throughput (consumed BW) increase when the packet error rate is increased in the TCP?

Tags: tcp, bandwidth, throughput, congestion

I was simulating TCP used by dailymotion.com, and I noticed that when I increased packet error rate, the consumed BW was increased. How?

Comment: retransmision ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Errors in transmission are detected in TCP layer.

The receiving TCP layer discards the damaged segment, forcing the sender to sent the segment again.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a reliable transport protocol, and it will request missing segments to be resent. The segments get sent, get lost or corrupted, and resent. This causes more data to be sent.